# how to change size of button in sweet alert

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

### How can I change the size of button in sweet alert.

[image: Screen like]

### The code is:

```
swal({
      title: `Are you sure to delete this news posted by ${news.users.user_name} ?`,
      text: `Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this post!`,
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then(willDelete => {
      if (willDelete) {
        this.props.deleteNewsPosts(news._id)
      } else {
        swal(`This news is safe!`)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: what want you to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS on the .swal-button class (if you want it to be more specific you can pass a classname property to that alert or to the buttons as described here: https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#configuration)